# How can I count up by one by using or adding various numbers in a list?

Tags: python, list, addition

I originally posted this before, but it was confusing. In order to make it more clear, I'll try to explain it a bit better.

Executing my code creates a list with the values: `[2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 14, 22, 35, 56, 90]`, which is just sequence that I appended into a list. I want to be able to count by 1 with these values. So, starting from 2, I need to be able to count up by 1 forever. For instance, to count to 2(the starting position), I choose the value 2 in the list and add it to a different list. To count 3, I use 3. To count 4, I use 4. However, to count to 5, since 5 is not actually in the list, I will need to add both 2 and 3 together, then add that result to the list. I want to be able to do this for all values past 1 (starting from 2). The most important thing to understand here is that I am only trying to prove I can do this. It's not meant as a functional counter, it's meant to be a proof of concept.

The list is created by adding the previous two numbers to get a third number, then subtracting that number by 1.

Here is the code:

```
def main():
    x = 2
    y = 2
    z = (x + y) - 1

    print x
    print y

    times = 10
    count = 0

    while times > 0:

        if count == 0:
            seq_list = []
            seq_list.extend([x, y])
            print seq_list
            count = 1
        else:
            seq_list.append(y)
            print seq_list

        z = (x + y) - 1
        x = y
        y = z

        print z
        times -= 1

main()
```

This code outputs each value created individually, as well as a list containing each previous number created. This creates the list: `[2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 14, 22, 35, 56, 90, ...]` `[(2 + 2) - 1] = 3, [(2 + 3) - 1] = 4`, etc.

Comment: I still don't understand the question.  Please tell us *exactly what you want the result to be*.

Comment: In other words, you want to prove that you can build all numbers between 2 and x by adding some or all numbers present in the list?

Comment: How do you know you even can? I can think of plenty of lists where no combination of elements will satisfy your criteria.

Comment: Post a sample input and sample output. It will explain the problem itself and you need not to explain anything.

Comment: The result will take the numbers created from the code which are stored in this list: [2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 14, 22, 35, 56, 90]. Then, it will count from 2 to however high the numbers may go. The output will just be a list: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ...], but those numbers will have been created by adding using exact values present in the first list, or by adding values in the first list because the value was not already present. Tim has it correct. I want to be able to add 2 or more numbers to create the counting.

Comment: I think this is similar to the mcnugget numbers, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem#McNugget_numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then a simple solution would be to collect all the possible combinations in a set and then check if it's a complete sequence of numbers:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l =  [2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 14, 22, 35, 56, 90]
>>> s = set()
>>> for i in range(len(l)):
...     for comb in itertools.combinations(l, i+1):
...         s.add(sum(list(comb)))
>>> sorted(s)
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,
 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43,
 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63,
 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83,
 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102,
103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118,
119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134,
135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150,
151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166,
167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182,
183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198,
199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214,
215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230,
231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 243]
```

As you can see, `242` is the only number that can't be reached via summation of your list's members:

```
>>> [i for i in range(2,244) if i not in s]
[242]
```

Of course, this approach is entirely brute-force - not a problem with small lists, but it won't scale nicely with larger ones.

Comment: Okay, so combinations() from itertools is able to find out how a number can be created from adding other numbers?

Comment: @LukeK15: It creates all combinations from a given iterable. In the first iteration, it does all combination of length 1 (single items), in the second iteration all of length 2 ((2,2), (2,3), (2,4) ...), then of length 3 etc.; then `sum()` adds all those together and places them in the `set`.

Answer (score 1):

Here you see, which combinations lead to which sum:

```
from itertools import combinations
from collections import defaultdict
def main():
    x = y = 2
    seq_list = [x]
    for _ in range(10):
        x, y = y, (x + y) - 1
        seq_list.append(x)
    print seq_list

    result = defaultdict(list)
    for i in range(1, 1 + len(seq_list)):
        for comb in combinations(seq_list, i):
            result[sum(comb)].append(comb)
    for k in sorted(result):
        print k, result[k]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not interested in the combinations then you can use the following to print all the numbers that can be reached using your sequence.

```
def check_sum(a, b, stop, total):
    return a == total or (a < total and b <= stop and 
        (check_sum(b, a + b - 1, stop, total - a) or check_sum(b, a + b - 1, stop, total)))

print [i for i in range(244) if check_sum(2, 2, 90, i)]
```

If you're interested in the more general question -- can all numbers be formed by a sum of numbers from the sequence a, b, a + b - 1... -- then you can use the following. It displays the first combination of numbers within that sequence which will add to the given total, or `None` if no such combination is found.

```
def combine_to_sum(a, b, total):
    if a == total:
        return [a]
    if a < total:
        r = combine_to_sum(b, a + b - 1, total - a)
        if r:
            return [a] + r
        return combine_to_sum(b, a + b - 1, total)

for i in range(300):        # or any large number
    print i, combine_to_sum(2, 2, i)
```

Comment: your algorithm should return None for 242

Comment: @PadraicCunningham No, because 242 can be reached by adding the next number in the sequence (145)

Comment: the OP is using a specific list of numbers

Comment: I'm posting this in case the OP or anyone is interested in the more general case.